# MS Test settings > TeamCity > 64bit

Tags: visual-studio, teamcity, mstest

I've configured my .testsettings file [as per instructions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256991.aspx) to run Hosts in 64bit.

[image]

But I don't see anything actually written to the settings file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TestSettings name="accounting" id="907240cb-5a90-45f4-a41f-2e73533c8c25" xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010">
  <Description>These are default test settings for a local test run.</Description>
  <Deployment enabled="false" />
  <Execution>
    <Timeouts runTimeout="1800000" testTimeout="40000" />
    <TestTypeSpecific>
      <UnitTestRunConfig testTypeId="13cdc9d9-ddb5-4fa4-a97d-d965ccfc6d4b">
        <AssemblyResolution>
          <TestDirectory useLoadContext="true" />
        </AssemblyResolution>
      </UnitTestRunConfig>
    </TestTypeSpecific>
    <AgentRule name="LocalMachineDefaultRole">
    </AgentRule>
  </Execution>
  <Properties />
</TestSettings>
```

And so my build server (Teamcity) continues to build in 32bit.

i've also tried setting it in VS but that definitely doesn't get persisted anywhere for Teamcity to know[image]

how do i force Teamcity to use 64bit ?